Scale issue when opening glb export in gltf-viewer
When I import my glb export to gltf-viewer it gets enormous, scale issue, I need to use such animated character from Mixamo for an AR project.
Would really appreciate some help, Link for 3D animated object:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1esyRfcVRGbu2FN9Vq9GXhEKJgV_NrFql?usp=sharing

Hi :) Perhaps it "gets enormous" in the gltf viewer because in Blender Object mode you have the X, Y and Z scales set to 100 ! (Object mode with model selected > Properties panel > Object Properties tab > Transform > Scale X=100, Y=100, Z=100). To fix this you need Apply the Scale so that scale X, Y and Z all = 1.00. To do this Object mode > select model > Ctrl + A (to open the Apply menu) > choose the Scale Option.
